# This regex is not right

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to use regex generators to create an expression, but I can't seem to get it right.

What I need to do is find the following type of string in a string:

```
community_n
```

For example, within the string which may be

```
community community_1 community_new_1 community_1_new
```

from that, I just want to extract `community_1`

I have tried `/(community_\\d+)/`, but that is clearly not right.

Comment: If the string was just `community_1_new` would you still want to match `community_1`?  Or only match exactly the word `community_1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding word boundries, so

`/(\\bcommunity_\\d+\\b)/`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regex (community_\d+).
Though I could be incorrect since I don't know which language you are using.
(For some reason I cannot add comments, I can only answer questions).